# React JS parsing data in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have facing an issue in React JS data parsing, i want to get `start_date` from JSON data

My code

```
//fetch appointment data
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments`)
    .then(res => {
      const appointmentdata = res.data;
      console.log(appointmentdata);          //result
      //this.setState({ appointmentdata: JSON.parse (appointmentdata.replace ("Array", ""))});

      this.setState({ appointmentdata });
    })
    }
```

react component:

```
<div className="col-lg-3">
          {this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => <p>{data.start_date}</p>) }
                    </div>
```

just initialize the state with appointmentdata: [], so that on the first render it contains an empty array instead of undefined.

**Error**
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.appointmentdata.map is not a function

**result**   `console.log(appointmentdata)`

```
<div id="root" style="border: 1px solid red; padding : 25px; width: 800px;">This is 'root' div.</div>
-->      
    [{"id":"1","start_date":"2020-05-09 15:30:00","end_date":"2020-05-09 16:00:00", "cust_email":"admin@gmail.com"},{"id":"2","start_date":"2020-05-09 00:00:00","end_date":"2020-05-09 00:30:00","cust_full_name":"mubeen","cust_email":""}]
```

How can i get value `start_date`.

What should i do? Anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: `const startDates = appointmentdata.map(({start_date}) => start_date)`

Comment: i added , but your code is not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11299053/yevgen-gorbunkov)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `appointmentdata` has already been parsed, so simply replace:

```
this.setState({ appointmentdata: JSON.parse(appointmentdata.replace ("Array", ""))});
```

With:

```
this.setState({ appointmentdata });
```

Now it's not working because you are passing an Array to `JSON.parse()`, but it expects a string containing valid JSON:

```js
// This works:

console.log(JSON.parse(`[{
  "id": "1",
  "start_date": "2020-05-09 15:30:00",
  "end_date": "2020-05-09 16:00:00",
  "cust_email": "admin@gmail.com"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "start_date": "2020-05-09 00:00:00",
  "end_date": "2020-05-09 00:30:00",
  "cust_full_name": "mubeen",
  "cust_email":""
}]`));

// This doesn't work:

console.log(JSON.parse([{
  "id": "1",
  "start_date": "2020-05-09 15:30:00",
  "end_date": "2020-05-09 16:00:00",
  "cust_email": "admin@gmail.com"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "start_date": "2020-05-09 00:00:00",
  "end_date": "2020-05-09 00:30:00",
  "cust_full_name": "mubeen",
  "cust_email":""
}]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If it's not working after making these changes, maybe on the first render that data hasn't been loaded yet, so it throws an error because `state.appointmentsdate` is `undefined`, so it can't find the `.map` function.

To fix that, you could replace:

```
{ this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => <p>{ data.start_date }</p>) }
```

With:

```
{ (this.state.appointmentdata || []).map(data => <p>{ data.start_date }</p>) }
```

Or:

```
{ this.state.appointmentdata?.map(data => <p>{ data.start_date }</p>) }
```

Or just initialize the `state` with `appointmentdata: []`, so that on the first render it contains an empty array instead of `undefined`.

Comment: if i render data in my component they giving error `{this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => <p>{data.start_date}</p>) }` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723993/danziger)

Comment: what change i do in my code? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723993/danziger)

Comment: Ok, that might be breaking only on the first render, but the code still has some other errors. Check the updated answer and see if that fixes it.

Comment: ok i try [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723993/danziger)

Comment: TypeError: `(this.state.appointmentdata || []).map` is not a function [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723993/danziger)

Comment: Then the result of your `console.log(appointmentdata)` is not what you posted. If this is failing, I suspect `appointmentdata` is an object with some other key inside, but definitely not an array.

Comment: i added photo `console.log(appointmentdata)` result you check [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723993/danziger)

Comment: @adnankhan Why does that have HTML markup like that `<h1>` or an HTML comment? Shouldn't that endpoint be returning only JSON?

Comment: If that's how it is, you might want to do something like `JSON.parse(appointmentdata.substr(appointmentdata.indexOf('-->') + 3).trim())`, but I think that endpoint should just be fixed to return a valid JSON response without HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
<div className="col-lg-3">
  {
    this.state.appointmentdata.length &&
    this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => 
     <p>{data.start_date}</p>) 
  }
</div>
```

First check the length and then start looping it using `.map`.

No need of doing `this.setState({ appointmentdata: JSON.parse (appointmentdata.replace ("Array", ""))});`

Instead you can do, if you are receiving data as array of Objects.

```
this.setState({ appointmentdata });
```

One more thing, `appointmentdata` should be defined as `[]` 
this.state { appointmentdata: [] };

Comment: problem is that they give error when render first time `TypeError: this.state.appointmentdata.map is not a function` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7079025/shiladitya)